# HTML5 File Reader API - image quality

Tags: javascript, html, filereader

hey i have this simple piece of code to read image from input file in a form:

```
 var reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onload = fileOnload;
        reader.readAsDataURL(file);
```

then i send the file binary via ajax, but when it comes an image and i save it the image quality is little bit lost, is there any way to specify in html5 quality of the image while reading that ?

Or it's only a server side problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The File Reader API doesn't modify the files. If the quality is being changed it is because you are modifying the file on the server (instead of saving it directly).

Comment: thank you man, indeed i was going to post a stupid question sorry, i'll accept your answer in 9 minutes